# Can I install WinRM on Linux for cross-platform PowerShell remoting?

Tags: python, linux, windows, powershell, remote-access

I want to run scripts using `Invoke-Command` from Windows to Linux.

I did some research and found out that I need PowerShell 7 to do this. So, I installed PowerShell 7 and tried running my script again:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host "Hi"
}
```

However, I received the following error:

> OpenError: [X] Connecting to the remote server X failed with the following error message: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer X. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to install or configure WinRM on Linux. I did some research and only found PyWinRM (a Python package), not instructions on how to do it with WinRM.

Is this possible?

Comment: May be a TLS issue.  Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: What does `$session` contain? The error message seems to be saying that the computer you are trying to connect to doesn't exist.

Comment: just servername... the issue is how to install winrm on linux server and not python package

Answer (score 0):

try PowerShellCore, maybe thats what you are looking for ;)
[PowerShellCore](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)

Comment: PowerShell 7 _is_ PowerShell "Core".

Comment: Right, I am just used to the old name.
anyways its what he needs ;)

Comment: You are telling OP to use the programming language they are already using. How is that helpful?

Comment: Default PS Version on Windows is still 5.1, he wanted to run from Win to Linux so I suggested he did upgrade on Windows to PS7 and tried the script again. For what I meant and linked is still called PowerShellCore on GitHub even the binaries reference on a PowerShell 7 file. anyways, from this point of view you need whatever its called on the Linux machine.

Comment: The second line of the question says "**So, I installed PowerShell 7**". You should thus assume they are using PowerShell 7 already.

Comment: yes, he said her researched and found out to use PS7 instead of default PS 5.1.
That's how I read it. I promise I will ask for clarification before answering the next time.

Comment: installed module POSH-SSH and I use it, if you have better suggestion I will be happy to hear

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install WinRM on Linux since WinRM is a Windows package. The cross-platform way to use PowerShell remoting in PowerShell 7 is to use SSH.

Follow the steps at [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.3) to achieve this. This page has further links within to help setup or install PowerShell and SSH on Linux or MacOS environments.

In short, you will need to install and configure the SSH service on the Windows machine (in addition to PowerShell, you'll need Win32 OpenSSH) you are remoting from, then do the same for the Linux environment(s) you wish to connect to.